# Trying to load Parse PFFiles into UITableView from query

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm a new, in training, swift programmer and have run into an issue with an app that I'm trying to put together.

I've searched through the forum and have found really helpful information but haven't been able to resolve my issue based on the results unfortunately.

I have an app set up to upload user images as PFFiles to parse but can't seem to have them download to the tableview in my table view controller. 
A majority of the code I have tried to implement hasn't caused any errors but also hasn't downloaded the desired images.

I apologize if this is a very basic issue but I've exhausted my researching outlets.

I have the images uploading to a single class called `Post` and want to be able to pull images based on the current user's ID.

I've tried querying the information but always have an error returned that says that the system was unable to find anything for the query. I'm not sure if there is a better way to upload and classify the information on parse or if I'm not coding the call back correctly. I'm essentially wanting to be able to retrieve the user's uploaded images and descriptions and display them on an "Account" page.

I'm working in Xcode 7.2 in Swift 2.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? It's hard to point to what you are doing wrong, or what steps you need to take to accomplish the task when we aren't able to see what you are doing.

Comment: Initially I was going to post some of the code but I ended up deleting the code to call back the images since I wasn't receiving anything in return. I can post the submission code if that would help.

Comment: Yes, whatever you can would help. As it stands now you are asking someone to completely solve the problem for you. Very unlikely to get someone to help with amount of work currently needed to answer your question correctly. If you can narrow down the problem by finding the mistake in your code will increase your changes significantly.

Comment: Understandable, Thanks for your quick response. Here's the code for the image upload view controller: 

http://mikecarpenter.co/xcodetext.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are three things we have to care about:

**1. structure of post**

It would be better if you store the User in a pointer. A pointer is easier to save and retrieve. (Pointers is a way to present one to many Relations, but in our case this means One to One).
So in the data browser(parse.com) replace the column "userID" with "user" type: Pointer, target class: User. 
Then in xCode

```
post["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
```

**2. Get All posts of a User**

Add this code:

```
      let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (obj: PFObject?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
        if err != nil{
            // DO something with the objets:
            myArray = obj
        }
    }
```

**3. Get the image**

Lets say you have a ImageView like imageView

```
    let file: PFFile = post["imageFile"] as! PFFile
    file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
        if data != nil{
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
```

**Now you're done:)**
**But just a little thing to improve your code:**

You don't need to dismiss the Alert after OK is pressed because if you set style to .Cancel this is automatically done! So change

```
     alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
```

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) })))

to

```
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpful. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: No problem :) Ps.: It would be great if you give the answer a up vote :)